# how to unwrap enums from dictionary in swift

Tags: dictionary, enums, swift, option-type

I have a `static func` that creates a dictionary from a bunch of enums in a struct.

It looks like this:

```
// Struct section starts here
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }

    // Must use static for non-instance methods
    static func createDeck() -> [Card] {

        var deck = [Card]()

        var n = 1
        while let rank = Rank.fromRaw(n) {

            var m = 1
            while let suit = Suit.fromRaw(m) {
                deck += Card(rank: rank, suit: suit)
                m++
            }
            n++
        }

        return deck
    }

}
```

The output is a nice bunch of enums when I call `Card.createDeck()` that look like this

```
{(Enum Value), (Enum Value)}
...
Lots of this
...
{(Enum Value), (Enum Value)}
```

I can even see the wrapped values if I do this:

```
for n in deck {
    println(n)
}
```

Which nets me lots of this:

`_TtV13__lldb_expr_04Card`

I can't figure out how to unwrap these enums; please can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You question doesn't make any sense. 1. What optionals are you referring to? 2. What is print out the first output you are referring to? 3. What is your actual goal? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: I edited to clarify some things - I may be mixing my terminology so I apologize - I guess I'm out of my depth. :-)  Output pasted is on the console in Playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: you have an array of card, not a dictionary.

Second: items in the array are not optionals hence no need to unwrap anything.

In for loop you can access card description:

```
for n in deck {
    println(n.simpleDescription())
}
```

Comment: Ugh - thank you so much!  I knew I was confusing myself somewhere!  I realized I was making an array when actually writing this `static func createDeck() -> [Card]`, but somehow I confused myself.  Thank you so much.  Sorry for being a muppet. :-)

Comment: Glad that you've figured it out :). Does code example solve your need?

Comment: Yeah - you absolutely nailed it.  I can now move on in the Swift Tour. ;-)  Thank you.